# Unity 2D Jump Animation C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 2d, sprite

I'm currently activating a trigger parameter to cycle the jump animation using:

`isGrounded` is my 'is player grounded bool', which I'm using to determine wether or not my player is allowed to jump. I'm using a child player object and using `Physics2D.lineCast(myPlayer, myPlayerGround, playerMask)` to do so.

I'm triggering the jump animation (using a trigger parameter to transfer to the jump animation from the run or idle, which are the only 2 other animations I'm using which currently work flawlessly) using the spacebar, the same way I tap in to the y axis jump velocity.

I can't figure out a reliable way to reset the trigger. I tried resetting it if `isGrounded` returned true, but then I'm assuming I'm getting a false positive, as it will only trigger in the first place if `isGrounded` returns a true? I also tried triggering the animation on by running a check to see if `isGrounded` returns a false, but if that's the case, the jump animation will play if I fall off a ledge, as well as actually jumping, which of course doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a couple of conditions, including the velocity direction and the isGrounded state. To reset the jump animation, you must be moving downward, and the isGrounded must be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

For perfect results in these kind of situation I always do trust on Delegates. You can use delegate such as your ground will through the message if players did land. [Here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113244/how-to-stop-jumping-again-when-character-is-in-air-double-jump/113247#113247) I gave a detailed implementation of exactly same scenario. Have a look at my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You must add conditions to your animations.

```
Animator.SetBool("isTouched", isTouched);
```

When you set new value, your animation will be animated. Take a look at [this](http://coffeebreakcodes.com/sample-projects/2d-mario-game-unity3d/) tutorial.